# EXCEL machine epsilon of grg solver

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I use very often the onboard solver of EXCEL (grg nonlinear) and I am quite happy with its
performance. Since I use the data generated by the solver for further calculations I would like to knwo the machine epsilon (error of my result).
Is there a way of estimating it or does the solver reports it and I have not been able to find it in the reports?

The formulae which I minimize by altering R_18 is

```
min=-3*K*(R_18)^\lambda+2*K*R_45*R_18^\lambda+s*R_18-R_46
```

All other quantities are known.

Comment: Are you talking about  reports appears in the Reports box of the Solver Results dialog box ?

Comment: Yes, I mea these reports. They do not really help me.

Comment: could you please specify that what error/problem you are finding while simplify it?

Comment: I am not finding an error, I am interessted in the error the algoritm (or solver routine) produces by rounding and so on.